# I want to print count of a particular field present in json.how to search for that field and print sum of all avlues associated with that field

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a json file which have fields like:

```
"EndTime" : "2019-03:06:11.786-04","startTime" : "2019-08-08T03:55:49.235-04","InstanceName" : "11623",Count" : "139"
```

I have to print the record count sum for all the values present in json using python. I have tried converting json into dictionary.

```
import json
total=0
count=0
with open('xyz.json')
```

I am expecting sum of count's value for all records

Comment: first, provide a xyz.json file example. Secondly, you did not try to convert the json into a dictionary, where is the code after `with open()`? Which errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)
    for line in json_data:
        if line["number_key"] == number_to_extract:
            counter += number_to_extract

     return counter
```

I think that's what you wanted, but without any concrete example i can't help you more than that

Comment: can the same be done in unix by shell scripting with an easy approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a proper JSON formatted file, your JSON file contains an array of objects with the fields in the format you specified, and each of the objects contains the field RecordCount, this should work:

```py
import json
total = sum([int(e['RecordCount']) for e in json.load(open('xyz.json'))])
print(total)
```

If your array is buried (e.g. in the `"Body"` field), you could do:

```py
import json
total = sum([int(e['RecordCount']) for e in json.load(open('xyz.json'))['Body']])
print(total)
```

Comment: Assuming that your JSON file contains an array of objects with the fields in the format you specified, and each of the objects contains the field `RecordCount`, the answer is yes.

Comment: You should publish an excerpt of your JSON file. It does not seem to be composed of an array of objects with the fields in the format you specified if you get that error.

Comment: Is your file a valid JSON? (Test it with `json.load(open('xyz.json'))`, if this does not throw an error, it is valid.) Is this the beginning of the JSON? The `"Body"` field contains an array. Are all the objects you want to sum in this array?